# Use of "seek distraction"

Tags: expressions

Here’s a sentence I wrote:

> These kids are not able to concentrate on a subject for a long period of time. They sit in front of a desk for five minutes, and then go on to/stop to ***seek distraction***.

What I am trying to say here is that these kids have quite short attention spans, so they need to have a bit of break every five minutes(crazy as it may sound).

Is the expression in bold correct? If not, how would you say it instead?

Comment: Distraction isn't something one would seek. One simply gets distracted. So, the expression isn't idiomatic.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, @Pkjmm! But I found out a meaning on dictionary.com, it says that "that which distracts, divides the attention, or prevents concentration". And it gives an example as followed:
"The distractions of the city interfere with my studies." Now I am a little bit confused lol

Comment: Although you could seek distraction from boredom, ADD kids wander *due to* the distraction they already feel. @Pkjmm has it right. In your example, it is the distraction that causes the interference, not the reverse.

Comment: @Pkjmm Not so, "seeking distraction" is perfectly idiomatic; see this: https://www.google.com/search?q=%22seek%20distraction%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en.

Comment: Do you mean to say that after a while the kids loose all interest and simply quit their studying and try doing something else like watching TV or reading comics so as to get some distraction? If so, then your expression is correct.

Comment: We don't 'loose interest', usually, we lose it.